# I am trying to insert values into a table from multiple tables (table relationships are shown)

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have four tables. The purpose of this code is for user to select a customer from a combobox and the check the shipments going to that customer to put into the FormHeaderTable. Let's pretend two shipments get selected.... forms can have several Shipments. Shipments can have several partnumbers

Table 1: **FormHeaderTable**

- FormID (pk)
- OrderKey(pk) (keeps track of how many forms have been made for a specific customer)
- CreationDate
- CustomerName

Table 2: **FormLineTable**

- LineID (pk)
- FormID, (pk, fk) (comes from FormHeaderTable)
- OrderKey (pk, fk) (comes from FormHeaderTable)
- ShipmentNumber (pk, fk) (comes from ShipmentHeaderTable)
- PartNumber

Table 3: **ShipmentHeaderTable**

- ShipmentNumber (pk) (rest of columns not needed for this question, just shipment details)

Table4: **ShipmentLineTable**

- ShipmentLine (PK)
- ShipmentNumber(PK, FK) (comes from shipmentHeaderTable)
- PartNumber

I need to insert values into my `FormLineTable` based on the `ShipmentNumbers` selected from a checklistbox that is populated by a customer combobox's selection.

I tried to do this:

```
Dim OrderKey As Integer
Dim LastFormID As Integer
Dim NextFormID As Integer


'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Get FormID and Get OrderKey
Dim MAXOrderKey As String = "SELECT MAX(OrderKey) FROM FormHeaderTable WHERE CustomerName = @CustomerName"
Dim MAXOrderKeyCommand As New SqlCommand(MAXOrderKey, con)

Dim MAXFormID As String = "Select MAX(FormID) FROM FormHeaderTable"
Dim MAXFormIDCommand As New SqlCommand(MAXFormID, con)

MAXOrderKeyCommand.Parameters.Add("@CustomerName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cboCustomer.Text

If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then con.Open()
Try
    LastFormID = CInt(MAXFormIDCommand.ExecuteScalar)
Catch ex As System.Exception
    LastFormID = 0
End Try
Try
    OrderKey = CInt(MAXOrderKeyCommand.ExecuteScalar)
Catch ex As System.Exception
    OrderKey = 0
End Try
con.Close()

NextFormID = LastFormID + 1
OrderKey = OrderKey + 1

       Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT FormHeadertable ON Insert INTO FormHeaderTable (FormID, CustomerName, CreationDate, OrderKey) Values (@FormID, @CustomerName, @CreationDate, @OrderKey) SET IDENTITY_INSERT FormHeadertable OFF ", con)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@FormID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = NextFormID
cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cboCustomer.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@CreationDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = Date.Now()
cmd.Parameters.Add("@OrderKey", SqlDbType.Int).Value = OrderKey




'this is where I need help'

     Dim cmd1 As New SqlCommand("Insert into FormLineTable (FormID, OrderKey, LineId, ShipmentNumber, PartNumber) Select FormID, OrderKey, ShipmentLineNumber, ShipmentNumber, PartNumber FROM ShipmentLineTable CROSS JOIN FormHeaderTable", con)
cmd1.Parameters.Add("@FormID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = NextFormID
cmd1.Parameters.Add("@OrderKey", SqlDbType.Int).Value = OrderKey

Dim isFirst As Boolean = True
For i As Integer = 0 To chkLstShipments.Items.Count - 1


    If chkLstShipments.GetItemCheckState(i) = CheckState.Checked Then
        If isFirst = True Then
            cmd1.CommandText += " WHERE ShipmentNumber = @ShipmentNumber" + i.ToString
            isFirst = False
        Else
            cmd1.CommandText += " OR ShipmentNumber = @ShipmentNumber" + i.ToString
        End If
        cmd1.Parameters.Add("@ShipmentNumber" + i.ToString, SqlDbType.Int).Value = chkLstShipments.Items(i)
    End If
Next

If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then con.Open()

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()  

cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery() 

con.Close()

 End Sub
```

My error

```
36 duplicate values or so...
```

Comment: I see now in my cmd1 query that shipmentNumber is an invalid column name for FormHeaderTable.. How should I make the query work in the way I need it to?

Comment: I needed to add a space in my cmd1.commandtext += " where......" still can't get the query to insert values in my FormLineTable as needed

Comment: Are you getting any errors after the correction? Also update your post with the changes.

Comment: You'll need the space before the `OR` statement as well.

Comment: made changes. I'm trying "from ShipmentLinetable cross join  FormHeaderTable" to see if this gets me what I need.

Comment: I would suggest testing your insert in SQL directly in SSMS with the test values and see what you get for a result. Then print your characters in your .net code and make sure those are the actual values being passed to your statement. Somewhere in that troubleshooting sequence you should find the issue.

Comment: Jacob is correct - get the sql correct then write the .Net otherwise you will be there troubleshooting a while.

Comment: Got it to work, cross join was a bad thing to try, it was the reason for all the duplicates values in my formlinetable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got rid of cross join section. switched FormId and OrderKey to the variables @FormId and @OrderKey and filled in these two variables with the variables I defined earlier in the code: NextNaftaId and OrderKey

New code looks like this:

```
    Dim cmd1 As New SqlCommand("Insert into FormLineTable (FormID, OrderKey, LineId, ShipmentNumber, PartNumber) Select @FormID, @OrderKey, ShipmentLineNumber, ShipmentNumber, PartNumber FROM ShipmentLineTable", con)
    cmd1.Parameters.Add("@FormID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = NextFormID
    cmd1.Parameters.Add("@OrderKey", SqlDbType.Int).Value = OrderKey
```